# show listTables on symfony2 in my view

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using `Symfony 2` and `Doctrine 2`, I want to show my list tables of my DB in my template SearchElement.html.twig

I try to execute this code

```
$tables = $sm->listTables();
```

in my `PageSearchController` but I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function listTables() on a non-object in
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP\data\localweb\Symfony2Test\src\Sftn\TestBundle\Controller\PageSearchController.php
>   on line 33

I was following this tutorial http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html#listtables

Comment: what is `$sm` ? **edit**: post your `PageSearchController::listAction` code

Comment: $sm : i was find it in this link http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/schema-manager.html#listtables of doctrine2 tuto

Comment: Did you get your `$sm` variable correctly? Like `$sm = $conn->getSchemaManager();` and `$conn` variable is a Doctrine Connection object?

Comment: thnx @TomaszKowalczyk and @bartek for answers but and i want to explain for me more , i try to write this in my controller `$sm = $conn->getSchemaManager();`
`$tables = $sm->listTables();` but the same error **Fatal error: Call to a member function getSchemaManager() on a non-object**

Comment: no one can help me please !! im a beginner in php and symfony2 just i need someone to help me that i can continue with right way

Comment: Sorry, but you need to get your "Programming Language 101" (with OOP) completed before you use tools like these. You don't understand what is going on, and the error is pretty much self explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try complete version for Symfony2:

```
$connection = $this->get('database_connection');
$sm = $connection->getSchemaManager();
```

Comment: thnx for you answer @drymek ... it's ok